# Unmanaged Exports / Robert Giesecke

Tags: .net, delphi, interop

In the following  answer Robert Giesecke describes a way to export managed code to native applications without the need of COM registration:

[Answer on stackoverflow from Robert Giesecke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787303/how-to-use-net-assembly-from-win32-without-registration)

I downloaded the UnmanagedExportLibrary.zip from and built the samples using Visual C# 2008 Express Edition for the .net part and delphi 2010 for the win32 part as described on his page. When i start the delphi application which calls the dll, i get an exception "unable to start application...".

Is someone able to post two working projects (.net / win32) using the "RGiesecke.DllExport.dll" to communicate with each other?

Thanks in advance, Michael

Comment: I think you posted the wrong link. There is nothing there from Giesecke.

Comment: Perhaps referring to this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043214/unmanaged-exports-cannot-compile-assembly

Comment: [Robert Giesecke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/35443/robert-giesecke)'s site is [here](http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/)

Comment: I have an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272593/robert-gieseckes-unmanaged-exports/19290984#19290984

Answer (score 0):

I got this working for a C++ client calling a function from a C# DLL. One thing I did notice was that one of the DLLs was missing from the raw project but *was* included in the project template. Also the MSBuild call didn't work from a path containing spaces (or from a path that was too deep). Moved it to a path with no spaces and everything was fine.

Stephen