# Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports

Tags: c++, .net, unmanaged, dllexport

I'm trying to get an DllExport from vb.net to unmanaged c++ working.

I'm using [Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) with Visual Studio 2012 and tried to follow this [very helpful hints](http://www.mql5.com/en/articles/249). I copy the dlls from the .Net project by an post build action in the directory where my *.cpp and *.h files reside.

I checked my dll with `dumpbin /EXPORTS Nugget.Discovery.dll` and it tells me that there are exports:

```
File Type: DLL
Section contains the following exports for \Nugget.Discovery.dll
00000000 characteristics
52554A05 time date stamp Wed Oct 09 14:20:21 2013
    0.00 version
       0 ordinal base
       2 number of functions
       2 number of names
ordinal hint RVA      name
      0    0 0000532E StartAnnouncing
      1    1 0000533E StopAnnouncing
Summary
    2000 .reloc
    4000 .rsrc
    2000 .sdata
    4000 .text
```

But if I try to import it in the cpp file with

```
#import "Nugget.Discovery.dll" 
   void StartAnnouncing(int serial);
```

I get one IntelliSense error and one error after I try to compile:

```
IntelliSense: cannot open source file "Debug/Nugget.Discovery.tlh"
error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'nugget.discovery.dll': Fehler beim Laden der Typbibliothek/DLL.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards! 
   Stefan

Comment: You are very much on the wrong track with this.  The #import directive is meant to import the type library of a COM component.  The Giesecke hack does not generate a COM component, it produces a plain DLL that just has exported functions.  You must use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress in your C++ code to use it.  Actually creating a COM component in C# is very simple, just use the [ComVisible] attribute.  Using a COM component in C++ however has a learning curve, you are likely to be starting at the bottom of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) I came to this solution:

This is my code on the managed side:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports RGiesecke.DllExport

Public NotInheritable Class Beacon

Private Sub New()
End Sub

Private Shared _nuggetAnnouncement As NuggetAnnouncement

' ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Local
''' <remarks>Cannot be called from managed code!</remarks>
<DllExport("StartAnnouncing", CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Shared Sub StartAnnouncingNative(serial As Integer)
    StartAnnouncing(serial)
End Sub

''' <remarks>Cannot be called from managed code!</remarks>
<DllExport("Test", CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Private Shared Function TestNative() As Integer
    Return Test()
End Function
' ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Local

Public Shared Sub StartAnnouncing(serial As Integer)
    'do something
End Sub

Public Shared Function Test() As Integer
    Return 42
End Function

End Class
```

Interesting is, that I cannot call functions that are marked with `<DllExport>` from managed code (even if they are Public).

And this is the code on the native side:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK* StartAnnouncingType)(int);
typedef int (CALLBACK* TestType)(void);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HINSTANCE dllHandle = NULL;   
StartAnnouncingType  StartAnnouncingPtr = NULL;
TestType TestPtr = NULL;
wchar_t dllNameWide[64];
int size = mbstowcs(dllNameWide, "Nugget.Discovery.dll", sizeof(dllNameWide));
dllHandle = LoadLibrary(dllNameWide);
if (NULL != dllHandle) 
{ 
  //Get pointer to our function using GetProcAddress:
  StartAnnouncingPtr = (StartAnnouncingType)GetProcAddress(dllHandle,"StartAnnouncing");
  TestPtr = (TestType)GetProcAddress(dllHandle,"Test");
  int test;
  if (NULL != TestPtr) test = TestPtr();
  int serial = 1;
  if (NULL != StartAnnouncingPtr) StartAnnouncingPtr(1);
  //Free the library:
  FreeLibrary(dllHandle);    
}
}
```

Are there any other better solutions?

Ciao!
Stefan

Comment: DllExport works by modifying the IL. That is why calling the methods does not work. It is best to mark the class as internal and the methods as private so there is less chance of calling them.

Answer (score 3):

As part of DllExport, a .lib file is generated. You can use that to use the normal C++ linker instead of LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress.

Starting from the managed code you posted, on the native side:

```
extern CALLBACK void StartAnnouncingType(int serial);
extern CALLBACK int TestType(void);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int test = TestPtr();
    StartAnnouncingPtr(1);
}
```

In the settings of you unmanaged project, add `Nugget.Discovery.lib` to the project properties: Configuration Properties->Linker->Input. And copy the Nugget.Discovery.dll to the output directory.