# How to Invoke C# dll from Matlab?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interoperating between Matlab and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434331/interoperating-between-matlab-and-c-sharp)

I need to use some functionality from a Dot Net C# managed-dll How can I call this Dot Net C# dll in matlab ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to make this work is to use COM. You can implement a COM object using .NET, and MatLab can work with COM objects (e.g. see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/exploring-your-object.html).

If your managed C# DLL is not yet exposed to COM, you may have to write a little wrapper (depending on whether or not you have access to the source code).

Comment: I've access to the source code ...
 I'll try this solution, and I'll accept this answer if I could make it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Matlab's `system`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command and this approach:

[Need to run a c# dll from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138812/need-to-run-a-c-sharp-dll-from-the-command-line)