# Can I compile a full C# project including a form to a dll then run them using rundll32

Tags: c#, dll

The reason i want to do this because my boss does not want my apps compiled as .exe, application that I created is only a simple application to display and edit data in the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138812

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207365

Comment: We should have a tag `boss` that would explain funny requests...

Comment: @Szymon `[pointy-haired-boss-request]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170019/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-net-dll-without-an-exe-to-load-it

Also, good luck with your ridiculous boss.

Comment: @Szymon yeah, I agree, and thanks to trope