# How to set an entry point for a dll in C# to execute the Rundll32.exe

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm working on a project, that requires I call an external dll.  I used VS 2012 to create the DLL (which works fine as an EXE file).  But, when I try to run the dll with the code below, I get an error say "..**Missing Entry Point**..".   I've looked, and have not found an example which clearly explains what the entry point need to look like, and how you do it in C#, not C++.  Appreciate the help. Thanks.

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "Mydll.dll,MyMethod" + localFile);

Comment: C# dll's are managed dll's, not native dll's, you can't execute them directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138812/need-to-run-a-c-sharp-dll-from-the-command-line

Comment: I don't think you can call managed dll using Rundll32. Here are few alternate options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138812/need-to-run-a-c-sharp-dll-from-the-command-line

Comment: rundll32.exe only knows about unmanaged entrypoints for a DLL.  The kind that you cannot create with C#.   You could with C++/CLI or an IL rewriter like Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports.  There is very, very little point to that when you use the Process class, just add a reference to the assembly.

Comment: If I register the dll to the registry would that allow it to run natively. And thanks guys for the help. I'm going to give the links you posted a try.

Comment: Why not just package the code as a .exe and run it that way? Alternatively, create a .exe that will load your .dll and invoke a method on a class that you specify on the command line.